# Count how many times each function gets called

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

I want to count how many times each function get called.
I have a wrapper to do the counting and save it into a global variable

```
def counter(f):
    global function_calls
    function_calls = 0

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        global function_calls
        function_calls += 1
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

and then other two functions to be decorated for counting

```
@counter
def square(x):
    return x * x


@counter
def addition_by_self(x):
    return x + x
```

Now when I call the function five time each the global variable `function_calls` returns 10. Which makes sense.

```
print(square(x=4))
print(square(x=4))
print(square(x=4))
print(square(x=4))
print(square(x=4))

print(addition_by_self(x=4))
print(addition_by_self(x=4))
print(addition_by_self(x=4))
print(addition_by_self(x=4))
print(addition_by_self(x=4))

print(f"Number of the function got called: {function_calls}")
```

running the file gives the output.

```
16
16
16
16
16
8
8
8
8
8
Number of the function got called: 10
```

Now I need some solutions or ideas on how to make the decorator return how many times each function got called, not an aggregation of all the calls. I might have other functions which I need track the number of times they also got called.

Essentially I want to do something like `print(function_calls) # or something proper`
and get the out like: `sqaure got called 5 times and addition_by_self got called 5 times`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a single global `int`, store per-function counts in a `dict`.

```
def counter(f):
    global function_calls
    function_calls = {}

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        global function_calls
        function_calls[f.__name__] = function_calls.setdefault(f.__name__, 0) + 1
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

`f` might make a better key than `f.__name__` (multiple distinct functions could have the same name), but this works as a simple example.

Comment: for some reason I get a keyerror why I execute the function with the error coming from `function_calls[f.__name__] += 1`. that is when I call the decorated function `square(4)`

Comment: Change the increment line to `function_calls[f.__name__] = function_calls.setdefault(f.__name__, 0) + 1`

Comment: @DennisWilliamson it works. Thanks. Do you know why the increment line didn't work. it look logical to me

Comment: @se7en: The dictionary doesn't have the key yet (thus no value 0 to start at) so there's nothing to increment.

Comment: Right, you might want to use `collections.defaultdict` or `collections.Counter` instead to simplify this.

Answer (score 1):

Using a list and an attribute:

```py
def counter(f):
    global funs
    try:
        len(funs)
    except NameError:
        funs = []
    funs.append(f)
    f.function_calls = 0

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        f.function_calls += 1
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper

@counter
def square(x):
    return x * x


@counter
def addition_by_self(x):
    return x + x

for i in range(10):
    print(square(3))
    print(addition_by_self(2))
    print(addition_by_self(4))

for f in funs:
    print(f'function: {f.__name__}, calls: {f.function_calls}')
```